# Как отобразить кириллицу в названии файла

Tags: java, файлы, servlet

Сохраняю файл из директории в браузере, но почему-то в место кириллические символы заменяются на символ `_`.

Пример:

```
 String fileName = "ПЛ5.111.008 СБ [1].tif".replace(' ', '-');
```

Сохраняется файл вот так - `__5.111.008-__-[1].tif`

Пример Кода:

```
 response.setContentType("text/html");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    response.setContentType("application/download");
    String fileName = "ПЛ5.111.008 СБ [1].tif".replace(' ', '-');

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment;filename=" + fileName);



    String test = request.getParameter("test");

    simpleDLL sdll = simpleDLL.INSTANCE;

    File file = new File("D:/file/ПЛ5.111.008 СБ/ПЛ5.111.008 СБ [1].tif");
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

    byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];//copy binary contect to output stream
    while (fileIn.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1) {
        out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
    }

    fileIn.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();          

    request.setAttribute("test", test);
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел способ это поправить:

```
String fileName = "ПЛ5.111.008 СБ [1].tif";        
    String URLEncodedFileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8");
    String ResultFileName = URLEncodedFileName.replace('+', ' ');


    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment;filename=" + ResultFileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно глобально установить кодировку

```java
try {
  System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
  Field charset = Charset.class.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset");
  charset.setAccessible(true);
  charset.set(null, null);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
  log.warn("defaultCharset property does not exist", e);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
  log.warn("charset.set(null, null): Illegal access exception", e);
}
```

Comment: И ваш вариант и мой в браузере мазила выводит коды кириллических символов , при этом в хроме все хорошо(